# react setState value from localstorage

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage

I want to set the default value of `itemStatus` to `true` if there is an item on local storage.
And I think the way I can do it is by check from the local storage so it will return the value since the first render. But when I make this code it seems not to work at all, when I run the first `console.log` I got `[]`, but the second `console.log` is always returning `true`. I'm not sure is there something wrong with my code? Or maybe there is another way I can use to set a default value that is dependent on the item on the local storage?

```
const checkItem = () => {
  let check = localStorage.getItem("My Item");
  console.log(localStorage.getItem("My Item"));
  if (check !== []) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};

const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [itemStatus, setItemStatus] = useState(checkItem());
  console.log(itemStatus);
  ....
}
```

Comment: Can you please mention what you are setting in localStorage?

Comment: What you expect from the 2nd console.log to print?

Comment: @Shiladitya it's a list of objects.

Comment: @Mateen it should be false if it's an empty array otherwise it's gonna be true.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this short way

const checkItem = () => !!localStorage.getItem("My Item");

Comment: it's always returning true, whether it's an empty array or not

Comment: it's checks if local storage undefined or not, if you want to check is array empty, you can add .length at the end const checkItem = () => !!localStorage.getItem("My Item").length;

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage.getItem()` always return `string` and this:

```
if (check !== [])
```

actually equals to this:

```
if ('[]' !== [])
```

and you get `true`

Comment: I see, so that's the reason why it's returning true. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
const checkItem = () => {
  let check = localStorage.getItem("My Item");

  //First check for null then check for length
  if (check && check.length) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};

const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [itemStatus, setItemStatus] = useState(checkItem());
  console.log(itemStatus);
  ....
}
```

Comment: it does work, but only when I refresh the page. Is there a way to update the value on re-render?

Comment: Yes, you should use useEffect with dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `useMemo` like this

```js
const hasItem = useMemo(() => !!)
```